# ImmutableList<T> check and remove

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I have a `System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableList<T>` and I want to check if an item is present inside of it and remove it in a single step. Something like this:

```cs
var newList = oldList.Remove(item, out bool found);
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Have you checked [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutablelist-1.remove?view=netcore-2.2#System_Collections_Immutable_ImmutableList_1_Remove__0_System_Collections_Generic_IEqualityComparer__0__)?

Comment: @HereticMonkey That method doesn't indicate whether or not the item I specified was actually in the list though

Comment: That page has a link to all of the methods of `ImmutableList<T>`...

Comment: @HereticMonkey None of them have this functionality

Comment: Then there's your answer; no. You'll need to write a method that does that for you. I would probably just check the length of the two lists; if they're different, it was found and deleted.

Comment: The only collection that I can think of with Remove method that returns bool is [`HashSet<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.remove). It removes and adds in O(1), but doesn't allow duplicate values

Answer (score 4):

Since that functionality doesn't exist out of the box, a simple extension method can give you what you need.

```
    public static ImmutableList<T> Remove<T>(this ImmutableList<T> immutableList, T item, out bool found)
    {
        found = false;
        if (immutableList.Contains(item))
        {
            found = true;
            return immutableList.Remove(item);
        }
        return immutableList;
    }
```

You can also do

```
public static ImmutableList<T> Remove<T>(this ImmutableList<T> immutableList, T item, out bool found)
{
    var oldCount = immutableList.Count;
    var results = immutableList.Remove(item);
    found = oldCount > results.Count;
    return results;
}
```

But as mentioned in the comments, neither of these are probably that efficient. A properly efficient model would likely need to be a custom implementation of `ImmutableList<T>` vs just an extension method like these.

Per [Slai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1383168/slai)'s recommendation this might be more efficient:

```
public static ImmutableList<T> Remove<T>(this ImmutableList<T> immutableList, T item, out bool found)
{
    found = false;
    var possibleLocation = immutableList.IndexOf(item);
    if (possibleLocation < 0)
    {
        return immutableList;
    }
    immutableList.RemoveAt(possibleLocation);
    found = true;
    return immutableList;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but is this the most efficient way to do this? It seems like it would require O(N) time for `Contains()` and again for `Remove()`.

Comment: Yeah, probably not the most efficient. Though I'm at a loss at the moment on how to increase that efficiency, at least without writing a new custom implementation of ImmutableList.

Comment: It's actually 3 x O(n) because `Remove` needs O(n) to find the item and O(n) to .. I guess copy the items to a new list(?). `IndexOf` can be used to find the item in O(n) and `RemoveAt` to remove it in O(n) without searching for it.

Comment: I think your second method is a tiny bit more efficient that my suggestion because `RemoveAt` checks if the index is within bounds. Just, it should be `found = oldCount > results.Count;`

Comment: There is a bug in the last one. Should be `found = true; return immutableList.RemoveAt(possibleLocation);`